# What are the conjugacy class and homotopy class of fundamental group in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, fundamental-groups

In the Zeta functions of graphs : a stroll through the garden 's  99 page , there is the define of conjugacy class, but I can't understand it well. Are there any difference between  conjugacy class and homotopy class?

Comment: What do you mean by "In the 's 99 page "?

Comment: @tessellation  sorry, just a book's 99th page ,I have edited it .

Comment: There is a bijection between  the set of free homotopy classes of oriented closed curves and the set of all conjugacy classes of the fundamental group. Here by free homotopy class, I mean homotopy without the base point. Alternatively you can assume free homotopy class as homotopy class of  maps from circle to the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A homotopy class is an equivalence class of walks, it's a topological notion. A conjugacy class is a group theoretic notion - the class of $g$ consists of all elements $x^{-1}gx$ for $x$ in the group. In a graph, each homotopy class contains a unique reduced walk, which determines the class.
A reduced closed walk is an element of the fundamental group.